# How to add a link to the navigation pinax(0.9a2)?

Tags: python, django, error-handling, navigation, pinax

I want to add new links to the standart bootstap theme in pinax. I tried to implement the  in my site:

```
{% block nav %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul>{% spaceless %}
            <li id="tab_profile"><a href="{% url profile_detail user.username %}">{% trans "Profile" %}</a></li>
            <li id="tab_notices"><a href="{% url notification_notices %}">{% trans "Notices" %}{% if notice_unseen_count %} ({{ notice_unseen_count }}){% endif %}</a></li>
        {% endspaceless %
            <li id="tab_first">
                <a href="#">First Link</a>
            </li>
        }</ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

but I get an error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /
>
> Invalid block tag: 'endif', expected 'endspaceless'

Therefore, how to add a new link to the navbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a syntax error, you didn't terminate `endspaceless` correctly:

```
{% endspaceless %
    <li id="tab_first">
        <a href="#">First Link</a>
    </li>
}</ul>
```

should be:

```
{% endspaceless %}
    <li id="tab_first">
        <a href="#">First Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```